# How do I stop new workbook generated by VBA script from opening

Tags: excel, vba

I created a script to save in a new Excel workbook with a spécific name part of the active workbook and it works as expected.

The issue is that the new workbook generated by my script opens and stays opened.

How can I stop the new workbook from opening ?

Here is the script :

```
Sub CopyWorksheetToNewWorkbook()
    Dim originalWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim newWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim newName As String
    
    On Error Resume Next ' Enable error handling
    
    ' Set the reference to the original worksheet
    Set originalWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AUDITEUR") ' Change "AUDITEUR" to your source worksheet name
    If originalWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source worksheet not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Disable error handling
    
    ' Get the name for the new workbook from cell A2
    newName = originalWorksheet.Range("A2").Value
    If newName = "" Then
        MsgBox "No name found in cell A2!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Create a new workbook
    Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    
    ' Copy the original worksheet to the new workbook
    originalWorksheet.Copy Before:=newWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    ' Rename the copied worksheet to the value from cell A2
    Set newWorksheet = newWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    newWorksheet.name = "AUDITEUR"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    newWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\pjpomerleau\OneDrive - Genuine Parts Company\1- OPÉRATIONS\PSS\TEST AUDIT\" & newName & ".xlsx"
    
    ' Delete the default empty worksheet in the new workbook
    On Error Resume Next ' Enable error handling
    newWorkbook.Sheets(2).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Disable error handling
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `newWorkbook.Close` Btw, you don't need `Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add`. `originalWorksheet.Copy`, without any arguments, will create a new workbook, which will then be the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new workbook it will open automatically. I tested your macro myself and added in two lines that closed the workbook after the unneeded sheet was deleted.

```
' Delete the default empty worksheet in the new workbook
On Error Resume Next ' Enable error handling
newWorkbook.Sheets(2).Delete
newWorkbook.Save
newWorkbook.Close
On Error GoTo 0 ' Disable error handling
```